# Detected a call to Model.fit inside a tf.function

Tags: r, keras

I have a dataset with two columns c1, c2. I want to predict c2 from the values ​​of c1.

```
data <- data.frame(c1 = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE), c2 = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

I created a simple neural network model with *keras* package but when learning I get an error:

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model <- model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(1)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)
model <- model %>% compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = optimizer_adam(), metrics = c("mean_squared_error")
)
features <-  matrix(train$dateInt, ncol = 1)
target <- train$Valeur
model <- model %>% fit(
  x = features, y = target,  
  epochs = 10, batch_size = 32  
)
```

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
RuntimeError: Detected a call to `Model.fit` inside a `tf.function`.
`Model.fit is a high-level endpoint that manages its own `tf.function`.
Please move the call to `Model.fit` outside of all enclosing `tf.function`s.
Note that you can call a `Model` directly on `Tensor`s inside a `tf.function` like:
`model(x)`.
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.
```